# Getting Error Message from payment gateway

Tags: payment-processor

A payment processor configured for this page might be disabled (contact the site administrator for assistance) 
I keep getting the above error when I visit the live page of my contribution.
what can i do about

Answer (score 2):

I did a workaround when i got this error:

- Edit the Contribution page
- Go to "Amounts"
- click "Test Processor"
- Save

I assume a prior processor wasn't showing up or configured after i reinstalled my server and re-enabled Drupal and CiviCRM.

By selecting a different processor, it fixes the problem. If you really need the original, i'm sure you can recreate the payment processor and set it.